# Print non consecutive lines from file given line number list

Tags: linux, grep, awk

Consider that after `grep`, `awk` and `grep` again I have a list of line numbers looking like this:

```
20
55
98
154
1100
...
```

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
grep '01/01' /var/log/some.log | grep 'some' | awk '{print $10}' | grep -vn 200 | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

I would like to now print those lines from that file, ideally by continue to pipe this command. Any ideas?

I know I could simply remove `awk '{print $10}'`and `awk -F ':' '{print $1}'` but for some reason when I do this I get no results, whereas when I try with the command posted above I do get the list of numbers.

Comment: Please provide sample input file contents and desired output: it might be better to rewrite the entire chain of commands.

Comment: *when I do this I get no results*: there must be a `200` somewhere else on all the lines that contain both `01/01` and `some`, so your `grep -vn 200` filters out all of them and not just those that have `200` in the 10th field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
| xargs -I{} sed '{}q;d' /var/log/some.log
```

See [How to get n-th line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/7659430)

**Comment:**

You could probably shorten your long sequence of pipes (including the above last step) by writing a more elaborate `sed`, `awk` or `perl` command:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[9] if /01\/01/ and /some/ and $F[9]!~/200/' /var/log/some.log
```